# please explain the behaviour of typedef here

Tags: c, structure, typedef

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  typedef struct  
  {
      int i;
      int j;
  }type1;
  typedef type1 type[10]; //Please explain this line ?
  typedef struct 
  {
      int  l;
      type  c;
  }type2;

  type2 x;
  x.c[0].i=1;   //How can we write this??
  x.c[0].j=2;

  x.c[2].j=3;

  printf("%d",x.c[2].j);
  return 0;
}
```

Program is compiling successfully which I'm expectecting not to because of

```
    typedef type1 type[10];
```

Please explain the behavior of typeded here.All I know is that we can define an alias with the help of typedef.

output:3

Comment: Make sure to fix the indention before posting any code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to read `typedef` is as a regular variable declaration, with the variable's type being the type that is being given an alias, and the variable name being the name of the new alias.

So, in

```
typedef type1 type[10];
```

if we drop the `typedef` we get:

```
type1 type[10];
```

This clearly defines `type` to be an array of 10 `type1`. So, the `typedef` is then introducing the name `type` for the type "array of 10 `type1`".

Comment: "The way to read typedef is as a regular variable declaration" :-) I use the same logic. makes understanding much easier.

Comment: Nice answer, I've never thought of type as a "variable". That way of thinking probably makes it easier to typedef things with more complex syntax, like function pointers and array pointers.

Comment: Dear unwind,

i have declared the variable c as 
type  c;but how can we access c[0],c[2]